# How do I find out the mode (permissions) of a directory?

Tags: perl

How do I find out the mode (permissions) of a directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [`perldoc -f stat`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#stat):

```
$mode = (stat($filename))[2];
printf "Permissions are %04o\n", $mode & 07777;
```

Answer (score 5):

Other examples require you to know that the mode is third item in stat output ( ie [2] ). File::stat lets you give symbolic name.

```
use File::stat ;
my $dir = '/etc/cron.d' ;
printf "%o", stat($dir) -> mode ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $mode;
(undef, undef, $mode) = stat($directoryname);
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /etc/cron.d`?

Answer (score 0):

Good answers so far. I wish to add an additional good module.

Most of the time, you only want to know the mode of a file so that you can manipulate it afterwards. [`use Fcntl qw(:mode)`](http://p3rl.org/Fcntl) or [`use POSIX qw(:sys_stat_h)`](http://p3rl.org/POSIX) export the necessary constants, e.g. `S_IXUSR`. I find this is unwieldy, even error prone as this is the rare time in Perl where you encounter mathematics with octal numbers and bit operators.

For this purpose, **[File::chmod](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3achmod) has the better interface** because it lets you express the change

- without the need to explicitely query the old mode and calculate the new one,
- in more familiar ways than octal, namely

  - symbolic, known from [chmod(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), e.g. `u-x`
  - like in [ls(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls), e.g. `-rw-r--r--`